# Javascript function that returns two different types of variables depending on input?

Tags: javascript, function, return, return-type

I'm trying to follow the rule and avoid repeating the same code.

I have this single function but depending on the input I want it to either return an array of objects or an object (not an array of just one object)

e.g.(the actual function is much longer and more elaborate than this one obviously, there are just the last few lines after a much longer calculation)

```
function (nameParameter, ageParameter, inputType)
{
  if (inputType === "asObject")
  {
    var x = {};
    x.name = nameParameter;
    x.age = ageParameter;
    return x;
  }
  else if (inputType === "asArray")
  {
    var y = [];
    y.push(nameParameter);
    y.push(ageParameter);
    return y;
  }
};
```

Is this possible and if so is it good practice? Is there some other way around it?

Otherwise I'll have to create two distinct function with almost the exact same code.

Comment: I think it ok(better then two different functions), JavaScript gives you `instanceof` to know object type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. Implement one version and add a wrapper function that converts the the other format you may want. That way the caller always gets consistent behaviour, and theres still no code duplication.

```
function asObject(nameParameter, ageParameter)
{
    //Lots of work here.
    var x = {};
    x.name = nameParameter;
    x.age = ageParameter;
    return x;
};

function asArray(nameParameter, ageParameter)
{
  //Just defer to the other version and repack its response.
  var o = asObject(nameParameter, ageParameter);
  var y = [o.nameParameter,o.ageParameter ]; 
  return y;
}
```

Comment: There's one case where I would deviate from this pattern, and thats where calling the more general form incurs a too large performance overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; that will work fine.

Javascript is not strongly-typed;  functions can return whatever they want, whenever they want.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by declaring the object and array with the values already set, but in my opinion if you have this strict type of coding it is not necessary to keep this function... Anyway, here is a simplified version:

```
function (nameParameter, ageParameter, inputType) {
    var ret;
    if (inputType === "asObject") {
        ret = {
            name: nameParameter,
            age: ageParameter
        };
    } else if (inputType === "asArray") {
        ret = [nameParameter, ageParameter];
    }
    return ret;
};
```

I left it without name and with a semicolon at the end because I guess it has been declared through a variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( typeof inputType == 'object') { 
  //object part of code
} else {
  //array part of code
}
```

Comment: Wrong. Execute this: `alert(typeof [])`, results `object`.

Comment: This is actually wrong. The "inputType" is a string that I'll be passing to the function so that I know what type to return. It's just a flag, it doesn't make sense for it to be an object or an array as it holds no actual values.